# Is Stack Exchange the name of the system used by SO, SU and this?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, stack-overflow-name

Is Stack Exchange the name of the system used by SO, SU and this?

There's nothing about in faq or "about" pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the shiny new [Legal section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal) at the footer, especially the [trademark section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) for name usage. It's on every one of the sites. I'll quote it here, as well.

> There is some confusion around the proper use and context of the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange name. Here are some guidelines:
>
> - **Stack Exchange Inc.** is the official name of the company.
> - **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written stackoverflow.com (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.
> - A **Stack Exchange site** is a Q&A website built on the technology of Stack Exchange Inc. The phrase "Stack Exchange" is generally used as an adjective, not a noun. One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51" (wrong).
> - The **Stack Exchange Network** refers to the collection of Stack Exchange sites and services.
> - **Area 51** (two words) is the site used to propose new Stack Exchange sites for the Stack Exchange Network.
> - The **Stack Exchange API** allows users to write applications based on the Stack Exchange engine. The API is always referred to as "Stack Exchange API", even if the application is written for a specific site (i.e. never Stack Overflow API, Server Fault API, etc.).
> - The **Stack Exchange Blog** is the company blog which talks about everything we're doing on all our sites and what the company itself is doing.

Comment: I updated with the newer info ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Me too :-P

Comment: @Rocket o boooo

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User are the original sites whos software was used to create the Stack Exchange Network. Stack Exchange is where users can create Stack Overflow-like sites on every imaginable topic: *"Can we use your engine to build a Q&A site about..."* whatever?

But the network itself is still in beta so there have been no other "Stack Exchange Network" sites launched, as of yet. Technically SO, SF, and SU *are* the first sites of the Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: No other Stack Exchange sites?  See:  http://www.stackexchange.com/directory/list  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @GreenMatt Those are SE 1.0 sites. Robert is talking about SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: @GreenMatt: You are correct. I should be more pedantic. "...there have been no other 'Stack Exchange *Network'* sites launched." The sites you linked are not part of the SE Network, but stand-alone legacy sites. I corrected my mis-statement.